# Available Matlab code to design Seismic Colored Inversion Operator?

Tags: geophysics, inversion, seismic, matlab

I want to apply seismic colored inversion technique to my datasets. Is there a Matlab code available that I can easily use? Are there any other recommended codes to apply seismic colored inversion?

Answer (score 5):

[Here is a link to a colored inversion operator design code written and provided by Peter Zahuczki.](http://peter.zahuczki.hu/index.php/myapps/clp)

This code requires that you provide a P-impedance log amplitude spectrum; he uses the open-source interpretation software [OpendTect](http://opendtect.org/) to compute this spectrum.

Peter has a easy to follow tutorial on how to use his code with OpendTect. Good luck!